# Laptop can't receive data sent by Raspberry Pi through serial communication

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, pyserial, uart

I am trying to send data from a Raspberry Pi to my laptop (UART) but I am not able to receive it in my laptop.

I get this following output on my pi (TX):

```
Serial status: True
4
4
4
4
...
```

On the other hand, I only get this output on my laptop (RX):

```
Serial status: True
```

Here are my codes so far:

TX.py

```
import os
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/ttys0',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
)

print("Serial status: " + str(ser.isOpen()))

while True:
    data = ser.write("help".encode())
    print(data)
    time.sleep(1)
```

RX.py

```
import os
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port = '/dev/cu.usbserial-14320',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
)

print("Serial status: " + str(ser.isOpen()))

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    print(data.decode())
    time.sleep(1)
```

Could anyone give me some advice I could look for please. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

in TX.py try this

```
if (ser.isOpen):
    while True:
        ser.write("help")
        time.sleep(1)
```

in RX.py try this

```
if (ser.isOpen):
    while True:
        data=ser.read(size) # here you have to specify the size of your data, 8 for example
```

I connected the RX and TX in my raspberry so I can read the same data that I've sent by my RPi and it works for me. So I hope it can help you in your case 
If this one didn't work, I think you have to make sure of the port you are using.
Good luck

Comment: I tried your code but it still doesn't work. How did you connect your module in your raspberry pi? I am using HC12.

I am using mac, that's why the port is /dev/cu.usbserial-14320.